# Strip EXIF data from image

Tags: javascript, exif

How can I strip the EXIF data from an uploaded image through javascript? I am currently able to access the EXIF data using [this exif-js plugin](https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js), like this:

```
EXIF.getData(oimg, function() {
    var orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation");
});
```

However, I have not found any way to actually remove the Exif data, only to retrieve it.

More specifically, I am trying to do this to get rid of the orientation Exif data which rotates my image on certain browsers.

Comment: @alex It currently does not seem possible for me to use PHP for this task. Even if there is no native Javascript function that allows this, a plugin would be acceptable. How can I edit my question to be less broad?

Comment: @alex, also with nodejs, it's not that extreme that you would want to handle this with JS. Even if this question is not about that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- look up the [file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format) and [exif format](http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html)
- [read the file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer) into [arraybuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer)
- [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) the required data and [remove it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice)
- create a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) from the remaining data
- [upload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) it with [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

---

Here is a little demo of it, select an image with orientation data to see how it looks with and with out it(modern browsers only).

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/frhwm2xe/3/

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#erd');
input.addEventListener('change', load);
function load(){
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = process;
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
    document.querySelector('#orig').src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
}
function process(){
    var dv = new DataView(this.result);
    var offset = 0, recess = 0;
    var pieces = [];
    var i = 0;
    if (dv.getUint16(offset) == 0xffd8){
        offset += 2;
        var app1 = dv.getUint16(offset);
        offset += 2;
        while (offset < dv.byteLength){
            //console.log(offset, '0x'+app1.toString(16), recess);
            if (app1 == 0xffe1){

                pieces[i] = {recess:recess,offset:offset-2};
                recess = offset + dv.getUint16(offset);
                i++;
            }
            else if (app1 == 0xffda){
                break;
            }
            offset += dv.getUint16(offset);
            var app1 = dv.getUint16(offset);
            offset += 2;
        }
        if (pieces.length > 0){
            var newPieces = [];
            pieces.forEach(function(v){
                newPieces.push(this.result.slice(v.recess, v.offset));
            }, this);
            newPieces.push(this.result.slice(recess));
            var br = new Blob(newPieces, {type: 'image/jpeg'});
            document.querySelector('#mod').src = URL.createObjectURL(br);
        }
    }       
}
```

```css
img{
    max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<input id="erd" type="file"/><br>
<img id="orig" title="Original">
<img id="mod" title="Modified">
```

Comment: Is there a way to replace the orientation with 1 rather than removing all the exif data? @Musa

Comment: @danial sure, you just have to know where the orientation data is and set the value in the data view, something like `dataview.setUint16(orientationOffset, newValue)`

Comment: How do I know where the orientation data is?

Comment: look up the file format and [**exif format**](http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html)

Comment: Hello, I tried to adapt your code for a different thing. Do you care explaining those codes (0xffd8 and 0xffda) what these are for, because my Jpeg is sure a different code..?

Comment: That is the first two bytes of the jpeg file 0xff then 0xd8 http://i.stack.imgur.com/X1OVR.png

Comment: On the second pass of the file, this turns up empty: process(process(file)) .. Here is a trace of what is happening: ```dv.getUint16(offset) == 0xffd8 true,
offset < dv.byteLength true,
app1 == 0xffe1 false,
app1 == 0xffe1 false,
app1 == 0xffe1 false,
app1 == 0xffe1 false,
app1 == 0xffe1 false,
app1 == 0xffe1 false,
app1 == 0xffe1 false,
app1 == 0xffe1 false,
app1 == 0xffda true,
pieces.length > 0 false```

Comment: `process` doesn't return anything, also it doesn't take any parameters

Comment: I see .. the jsfiddle works fine, I can process the image several times.  I am running the code on nodejs and I'm getting the exact same filtered image as the jsfiddle, however, the second pass through your code in nodejs turns out an empty image..  What happens if onload receives an `undefined`?  I think it is gracefully skipping the filter on the second pass so  the bug is not as obvious.

Comment: I just made a question out of it.  Here is a possible bug:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490122/strip-exif-data-from-image-node-js-addressing-a-possible-bug-in-the-original-v

Comment: @musa in my case I can not touch the stored images on the DB and I need to remove the EXIF data on the front end.  How can your code be modified this so the EXIF data is stripped from a image coming from the server? Thanks

Comment: If you're using ajax to get the image data you can use the same process function with the response of your ajax(as an array buffer) to create the data view.

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 3):

### **Removing EXIF data from images.**

Exif data exists only in TIFF, JPEG(JPG) & HEIC, but not in png, gif images.

First, let's understand what an image contains

### Contents of an Image

The image buffer contains a header(2 bytes) + data.

The data part contains many segments, and every segment contains a header(2bytes) + data.

Length of segment presents in 1st byte of data (or after 2bytes from the segment start)

**Exif buffer segment  starts with '0xFFE1'**

[header=marker]

### Steps to remove EXIF data

1. read the image as a buffer
2. iterate through each segment
3. if a segment has EXIF data, remove the segment

The below code is in TS ( just remove types, it'll work in js )

```js
const cleanBuffer = (arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer) => {
  let dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
  const exifMarker = 0xffe1;
  let offset = 2; // Skip the first two bytes (0xFFD8)

  while (offset < dataView.byteLength) {
    if (dataView.getUint16(offset) === exifMarker) {
      // Found an EXIF marker
      const segmentLength = dataView.getUint16(offset + 2, false) + 2;

      // Update the arrayBuffer and dataView
      arrayBuffer = removeSegment(arrayBuffer, offset, segmentLength);
      dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer)
    } else {
      // Move to the next marker
      offset += 2 + dataView.getUint16(offset + 2, false);
    }
  }

  return arrayBuffer;
};

const removeSegment = (buffer: ArrayBuffer, offset: number, length: number) => {
  // Create a new buffer without the specified segment
  const modifiedBuffer = new Uint8Array(buffer.byteLength - length);
  modifiedBuffer.set(new Uint8Array(buffer.slice(0, offset)), 0);
  modifiedBuffer.set(new Uint8Array(buffer.slice(offset + length)), offset);

  return modifiedBuffer.buffer;
};
const removeExifData = (file: File): Promise<File> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (file && file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
      const fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = function (this: FileReader) {
        const cleanedBuffer = cleanBuffer(this.result as ArrayBuffer);
        const blob = new Blob([cleanedBuffer], { type: file.type });
        const newFile = new File([blob], file.name, { type: file.type });
        resolve(newFile);
      };
      fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    } else resolve(file);
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes, needs more upvotes!